# How little o can verify for one example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, self-learning

I have following facts:

$n^2log_2n+n^2$ = $o(n^3)$

how I can understand this is true fact? I'm not rain into a homework question, any intuitively idea to quickly find or doing by math?

Comment: Could you think of any upper bound?

Comment: Wouldn’t this imply $\log_2 n  = o(n)$, which is not true?

Comment: @Oбжорoв What??? $\log_2(n)$ is certainly $o(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if $\frac{n^2\log_2(n)}{n^3}+\frac{n^2}{n^3}$ tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. This can be easily checked. We know that
$$\frac{n^2\log_2(n)}{n^3}+\frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac{\log_2{n}}{n}+\frac{1}{n}$$
$1/n$ tends to 0, it is a basic property of limits, which can be verfied computationally, and $\frac{\log_2(n)}{n}$ can be verified by [L'Hôpital's rule](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/lhospitalsrule.aspx).
In general, $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$$
This expression means that as we put larger and larger values of $n$ in $f(n)/g(n)$, the result gets closer and closer to 0. This is the mathematical definition, but it is equivalent to the computer science definition.

Comment: @JessicaAllen oh ok. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that @JessicaAllen. I edited it again.

Comment: @JessicaAllen was my answer helpful? If yes, you can click the accept button (the tick button). If no, please tell me what my answer missed.